# Bot doesnt want to take id from db

Tags: mongodb, discord, discord.js

I'm making a command where u can setup a bot status channel. Everything so far worked fine, db even writes down id of guild and channel but when I want to use it in `ready.js` is says its not defined.

Little help would be handy and grateful

Code:

https://pastebin.com/GnxtxFwG - main command

https://pastebin.com/hhy90czw - schema

https://pastebin.com/jVDGu43T - error

Error file:

```
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { channelId } = require('../../schemas/status');
    
module.exports = {
  name: "ready",
  once: "true",
  async execute(client) {
    console.log(channelId)
    console.log('Bot is up and ready to work!')

    const uptime = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor('ffd9c0')
      .addFields(
        { name: 'Capy is back and online!', value: 'Bot was probably offline due to a bug or maintenance.'},
        { name: '\u200b', value: 'If Capy isnt working how is he supposed to be contact on of our Developers or contact <@574849327650963469> directly.'},
      )
      
    const channel = await client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
    channel.send({ embeds: [uptime] });
    
    setInterval(client.pickPresence, 10 * 1000);
  },
};
```

Comment: "_when i want to use it in ready.js is says its not defined._" What is "_it_" here and what, what is the error message being returned, and what line of code is triggering the error?

Comment: "It" terminal yea mb i fixed the message. 
const channel = await client.channels.cache.get(channelId); this line and channelId specifically

Comment: Can you post all relevant code in your question as a code block. The goal of this forum is to provide information for the future. This will not be achieved through the usage of links that may expire in the near future

Comment: All of the links are lifetime variants but sure why not

Answer (score 0):

Client on function

```js
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { Statuses } = require('../../schemas/status');
const uptime = require('../../commands/tools/status')

module.exports = {
  name: "ready",
  once: "true",
  async execute(client) {
    console.log(Statuses.channelId)
    console.log('Bot is up and ready to work!')
    const uptimeEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor('ffd9c0')
      .addFields(
        { name: 'Capy is back and online!', value: 'Bot was probably offline due to a bug or maintenance.'},
        { name: '\u200b', value: 'If Capy isnt working how is he supposed to be contact on of our Developers or contact <@574849327650963469> directly.'},
      )
  
    const channel = await client.channels.cache.get(Statuses.channelId);

    Statuses.findById({ channelId: message.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
      if (data) {
        channel.send({ embeds: [uptimeEmbed] });
      } else {
        new Statuses ({
          guildId: interaction.guild.id,
          chnanelId: uptime ? uptime : "None"
        }).save()
        console.log("Status channel wasnt set on this server yet!")
      }
    });

    setInterval(client.pickPresence, 10 * 1000);
  },
};
```

Schema

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
         
const statusSchema = new Schema({
  guildId: String,
  channelId: String,
});
         
module.exports = model("Status", statusSchema, "Statuses");
```

Main command

```
const {
  SlashCommandBuilder,
  ChatInputCommandInteraction,
  EmbedBuilder,
} = require("discord.js");
    
const Statuses = require('../../schemas/status');  
    
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("status")
    .setDescription("Select the language of the bot")
    .addChannelOption(uptime => {
      return uptime
        .setName("channel")
        .setDescription("Channel you want to send the FAQ embed in")
        .setRequired(true)
    }),

  /**
    *
    * @param {ChatInputCommandInteraction} interaction
    * @param {Client} client
    */
    
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const { options } = interaction;
    const uptime = options.getChannel("channel");
    const user = interaction.user;
    
    const status = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor("#bb6464") 
      .setDescription(`Status message was set to ${uptime}!`)
      .setFooter({ text: `Request from ${interaction.user.username}`, iconURL: user.displayAvatarURL()})
      .setTimestamp(); 
          
    const status2 = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor("#bb6464") 
      .setDescription(`Status message was changed to ${uptime}!`)
      .setFooter({ text: `Request from ${interaction.user.username}`, iconURL: user.displayAvatarURL()})
      .setTimestamp();   
    
    let statusProfile = await Statuses.findOne({ channelId: interaction.guild.id });
    if (!statusProfile) {
      statusProfile = await new Statuses({
        guildId: interaction.guild.id,
        channelId: uptime,
      });
    
      await statusProfile.save().catch(console.error);
      interaction.reply({ embeds: [status] }) 
      console.log(statusProfile);
    } else {     
      await interaction.reply({ embeds: [status2] });
      console.log(statusProfile);
    }  
  }
}
```